# Will there be further moderator elections?

Tags: support, election

I know SE sites' community moderators are elected by the community. The last and only election on GameDev [was in 2011](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election).

Do these elections happen periodically or just that once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding if there's pressure to add another moderator, or an existing moderator steps down, then they'll have an election.

I don't think existing moderators have to re-nominate themselves, it's purely an additive basis.

Do you feel we need another election?

Comment: Another election seems unnecessary. Moderators should not be added until the need is obvious and they should most certainly not be replaced except under extreme circumstances. I wanted to check if I agree with the site's policy and I'm glad I do!

Answer (score 1):

I think they only happen when they need to happen, generally at most once per year; so far there's been no need for another one.